# Brakes Stick Until Clutch Pedal is Released

Tags: brakes, subaru, manual-transmission

Okay, pretty weird phenomenon here with my 2005 Subaru Forester. This typically only happens when my car has been sitting for a night or so. I'll depress the clutch, fire it up, pop it in reverse and then try and back out, but the brakes are stuck on. This occurs regardless of whether or not the e-brake has been applied, and it's been happening for at least six months now. I was convinced it was a problem with the calipers, but I've recently discovered that if I disengage the clutch first (pop the car in neutral, let clutch pedal out, re-engage clutch pedal, engage reverse), the brakes unstick *completely.* I have no idea why this could be happening, as far as I'm aware the two systems are completely separate.

My clutch pedal has also been soft lately until I give it a few pumps, but I've diagnosed this as a failing master cylinder, and this same problem has been occurring for a while before that started.

Anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your vehicle may be equipped with a "hill-holder" feature which will hold brake pressure when on an incline, even with your foot off the brake. It's a Subaru trademark for many years.

If the situation you describe is not happening on a sloped surface, the sensors involved in actuating the hill-holder may be failing/failed.